# Turning a method implemented in superclass into abstract

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

I have a Java program with the following classes in it

```
public class A{
     protected String name;
     ...
     @Override
     public boolean equals(Object obj){
          if(!(obj instanceof A)){
              return false;
          }

          A a = (A)(obj);
          return a.name.equals(this.name);
     }
}

public abstract class B extends A{
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        return equals2(obj);
    }

    public abstract boolean equals2(Object obj);
}

public class C extends B{
    private String data;
    ...
    @Override
    public boolean equals2(Object obj){
        if(!(obj instanceof C)){
            return false;
        }

        C c = (C)(obj);
        if(c.data.equals(this.data)){
            return c.name.equals(this.name);
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to force all classes extending `class B` to implement their own `equals` methods without having to use `equals2` like the example?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is to throw an exception in `B`s `equals`:

```
public abstract class B extends A {
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

This will ensure that sub-classes of `B` that fail to override `equals` will not fallback to `A`'s implementation of `equals`.

Unfortunately, this will result in run-time exceptions, as opposed to compile time errors, which are preferable.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, you could have the abstract class `B` throw an exception in its `equal()` method:

```
public abstract class B extends A{
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("add your own implementation");
    }

    public abstract boolean equals2(Object obj);
}
```

Then, anyone subclass of `B` which attempted to default to the inherited `equals` method would not work, forcing them to implement their own version.